# Admin password change for HP Color LaserJet CP4020 printer

Tags: passwords, printer, administrator

I'm having an issue logging in to the administrative functions with an HP Color LaserJet CP4020 model printer. I contacted HP about the problem, but they weren't any help since it's no longer under warranty.

The printer is a network printer in a business office setting. I recently set an admin password in the printer's web console (type in the printer's IP, go into Settings, changed the password). I was able to log in to the administrative functions successfully with that password.

The network administrator wanted to change the password by adding three more characters to the end password. In order to do that, I went back in to the same admin interface and typed the three new digits at the end of the password.

I'll try to articulate this part as best I can: at the time, the password was still hidden (just a series of black circles). I typed the three new characters at the end of the circles. I think my mistake was that I didn't clear the box entirely and then retype the entire password.

So basically:

"OriginalPassword" was shown as ********** in the "password" box and I just typed "123" at the end of **********. So it was **********123 which then became *************.

I hope that makes sense. Either way, I am now no longer able to log in with either the previous password or the previous password + 3 new characters.

Do I need to just factory reset the machine? I can't seem to find instructions on that and, as I said, the HP chat support hasn't been helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the password, then the only way is to do a factory reset. As the printer will lose all settings, including IP addressing, print a Config Page first, so you can set it up again. The instructions are [here](http://techzeus.com/everything-print/cold-reset/hp-color-laserjet-cp4020):

Press the Home button.

```
Press the down arrow ▼ to highlight the CONFIGURE DEVICE menu, and then press the OK button.
Press the down arrow ▼to highlight the RESET menu, and then press the OK button.
Press the down arrow ▼to highlight the RESTORE FACTORY SETTINGS menu, and then press the OK button to reset the product to the original factory settings.
```